# Optimal images alignment in container to make them maximal in size (with resizing)

Tags: algorithm, layout

I have an algorithmic problem that I cannot resolve. Let's say I have a rectangular workspace with X width and Y height and N rectangular images with x width and y height(all of them have the same size). Now I would like to align them in the workspace but I can do it in various cases. I would like to choose the case where images have maximal size.

Conditions:

- images can be resized but all of them must be resized with the same value
- ratio of images must be kept.

Is there any solution for problems like that? It seems a little like a cutting optimalization but with resizing.

Example:

- Workspace: 1000x1000
- Image size: 300x200
- Number of images: 5

Solution:

- Scale: 5/3
- Image after resizing: 500x333
- Alignment: 2 in row and 3 in column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to refer to the dimensions of your workspace and images with the usual letters `W` and `H` for width and height instead of `X` and `Y`.

So your workspace size is `(W, H)`, your image size is `(w, h)` and you have `N` images to fit.
Compute `p = (W*h) / (H*w)`, `r = round(sqrt(N * p))`, and `c = ceil(N / r)`.
Your alignment will be `r` rows and `c` columns. You can then scale your images so that `w*c = W and h*r <= H` or `w*c <= W and h*r = H`.

Comment: But if the workspace and images will be squares then always p = 1 and c = 2.

Comment: No? `p = 1` in that case, but if for example `N = 5`, then `r = 3` and `c = 2`.

Comment: However, I just realized I made a mistake and this solution doesn't work for every input. I think I've corrected it.

Comment: Your example confirmed that p=1 and c=2 in that case. 
If p = 1 then r=N/2 (ceil of this supposing that .5 rounds up to 1) and c=N/(N/2)=2.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it ;)

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan Oh right, my bad. I don't know what happened between my mind and my keyboard there.

Comment: Ok, that works great, thanks! And also I've realized how to get those equations when checking it so I guess I've learnt something new today too :)